# Enable Guard Malloc for iphone

Tags: iphone

i tried Run Gurad malloc for my app and i got this message
**GuardMalloc: Allocations will be placed on 16 byte boundaries.
GuardMalloc:  - Some buffer overruns may not be noticed.
GuardMalloc:  - Applications using vector instructions (e.g., SSE or Altivec) should work.
GuardMalloc: GuardMalloc version 18**

i dont know what is this good or bad???

Answer (score 1):

This is just a warning, it will still work as expected.

Comment: so whats the benefit of using that??  how to check the results

Comment: hey now i cant run my app on simulator ?? whats wrong?? my app just quits   ooh god

Comment: Guard malloc makes everything run VERY slow, make sure you're not running out of time during applicationDidFinishLaunching: